# Curl to $http.post() for Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, curl, post

Can someone tell me how I can go about converting this curl code listed below to $http.post() for angular js? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
curl https://example.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations.json \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"organization": {"name": "My Organization"}}' \
 -v -u {email_address}/token:{api_token}
```

So far I have the following angularjs code set up:

```
                     $http({
                            method : "POST",
                            url : url,
                            data : angular.toJson($scope.form),
                            headers : {
                                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                            }
                        }).then(Success,Failure);
```

I just have no idea how to setup the email address and token with the call.

Comment: What you have tried so far in the attempt to convert towards `$http.post()` ?

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have tried so far.

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. You really don't want to expose your api token/key. You should create a back-end service that will forward that information.

Comment: I have a backend service set up to call the api token when needed so thats not gonna be much of a problem. What I need is to just convert this curl for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best advice I could give you is to refrain from making CORS requests on the front-end. You want to have separation of concerns and it would be better for your back-end to call the api token and then parse that data into JSON. In the end, you have a back-end endpoint/route in which the front-end can send a request for data.

In your back-end, the route you have set up will look something like this:

```
router.post('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    request('https://example.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations.json', {
        headers: { ... }, token: { ... }
    }).then((result) { res.json(result) };
});
```

In your Angular factory/service, you'll be making a HTTP request like so:

```
$http.post('localhost/api/data')
    .then((response) => { response = response.data })
    .catch((error) => { if (err) { console.log(err) })
```

I hope this helps!